# Ошибка "встречено 'else', а ожидался оператор"

Tags: pascalabc.net

Выдает ошибку, что поставить?

> Встречено 'else', а ожидался оператор (строка 19)

```
var a, b, c, d, x1, x2: real;
begin
  writeln ('ax2+bx+c=0');
  write ('a=');
  readln (a);
  write ('b=');
  readln (b);
  write ('c=');
  readln (c);
  d := (b*b)+(4*a*c);
  if (a = 0) then
    write ('Уравнение не является квадратным.')
  else
    if (d > 0) then
      d:= sqrt(d);
      x1 := (-b+d)/2;
      x2 := (-b-d)/2;
      write ('x1=', x1, 'x2=', x2);
    else
      if (d = 0) then
        x1 := (-b-d)/2
        write ('Единственный x=', x1)
      else
        write ('Корней нет');
end.
```

Comment: `if условие then begin код end else`. Если вы хотите выполнить несколько операторов в условиях(циклах и т.д.) вам необходимо их "сгруппировать" с помощью begin end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Простые условия должны записываться в виде

```
if .. then
  одна строчка кода
else
  одна строчка кода
```

Если же вам нужно выполнить несколько строк или блоков кода по условию, то следует обернуть их в `begin .. end` вот так:

```
if .. then
begin
  ..
  несколько строк кода
  ..
end
else
begin
  ..
  несколько строк кода
  ..
end
```

---

Для вашего случая:

```
if (d > 0) then
begin                         <<-- тут нужно начать блок
  d:= sqrt(d);
  x1 := (-b+d)/2;
  x2 := (-b-d)/2;
  write ('x1=', x1, 'x2=', x2);
end                           <<-- тут нужно закончить блок
else
                              <<-- тут блок begin-ом начинать не нужно, т.к. if это уже блок
  if (d = 0) then
  begin                       <<-- тут нужно начать блок
    x1 := (-b-d)/2
    write ('Единственный x=', x1)
  end                         <<-- тут нужно закончить блок
  else
    write ('Корней нет');
```