# программа на паскаль в конце выдает не нужную строку

Tags: pascal

```
program one;
var 
  a, b, x: real;
begin
  writeln('a='); 
  read(a);
  writeln('b='); 
  read(b);

  if -b/a < 0 then
    writeln('нет решения')
  else 
    x := sqrt(sqrt(-b/a)); 
  writeln('x=',x);
end.
```

при условии что, `a=0` программа должна выдавать `"нет решения"`, но после неё появляется `"x=0"` так быть не должно.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (a = 0) or (-b / a < 0) then
begin
  writeln('нет решения');
end
else 
begin
  x := sqrt(sqrt(-b/a)); 
  writeln('x=',x);
end;
```

Обратите внимание на последовательность проверки условий в `if`. В случае `а` равного нулю значение булевского выражения известно после проверки первого условия. Второе условие в этом случае не проверяется (если в опциях проекта не включено "Complete boolean evaluation"), и исключения от деления на ноль не произойдет.

Comment: Не для себя прошу, но для тех кто несведует, поясните порядок в условии, ибо если поменять местами проверки - будет исключение =)

Answer (score 1):

Программа делает именно то что вы в ней написали. Если вам надо выполнить несколько строк внутри ветки `else` - объедините их в один блок с помощью `begin .. end`.

```
if (a = 0) or (-b/a < 0) then
  writeln('нет решения')
else 
begin
  x := sqrt(sqrt(-b/a)); 
  writeln('x=',x);
end;
```

Еще ответ по теме: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/933518/177188

Comment: Минус или нет - но ваше решение "упадет" при услвии a=0, вы бы хоть вчитались в код и вопрос автора =) деление на ноль - генерирует исключение =)

Comment: Зависит от настроек компилятора. Не помню паскаль, но емнип там по умолчанию будет не исключение, а NaN. Поправил код, спс.